# How to add Kafka as bounded source with Apache Flink 1.12 with DataStream API Batch mode

Tags: apache-flink

I want to use Kafka source as a bounded data source with Apache Flink 1.12, I tried it using FlinkKafkaConsumer connector but it is giving me the following reason

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected an UNBOUNDED source with the 'execution.runtime-mode' set to 'BATCH'. This combination is not allowed, please set the 'execution.runtime-mode' to STREAMING or AUTOMATIC
at org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:198) ~[flink-core-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]

Based on the flink latest documentation we can use Kafka as a bounded source, but there is no example provided on how it is possible, also nowhere it was mentioned it is the best way to go ahead with this approach.

Can someone help me to get some example working code to achieve this usecase

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example:

```java
KafkaSource<String> source = KafkaSource
        .<String>builder()
        .setBootstrapServers(...)
        .setGroupId(...)
        .setTopics(...)
        .setDeserializer(...)
        .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
        .setBounded(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
        .build();

env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.forMonotonousTimestamps(), "Kafka Source"));
```

See [the javadocs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/connector/kafka/source/KafkaSourceBuilder.html) for more info.